# Converting base64 to .jpg file, then saving in Django database

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, base64

```
def upload_image(request):
    if request.is_ajax and request.POST:
        image = request.POST.get('image')

        image_name = request.POST.get('image_name')

        imgdata = base64.b64decode(image + '==')

        extension = image_name.split('.')[1].lower()

        image_name = '{}_{}_profile_image.{}'.format(request.user.first_name, request.user.last_name, extension)

        with open(image_name, "wb") as image_file:
            image_file.write(imgdata)

        upload = ProfileImage(
            file=image_file,
            user = request.user.username
            )
        upload.save()
    data = {

    }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

I am trying to crop images in Django using Croppie.js. The images are then uploaded to an S3 bucket.

I have the cropping working and it is returning the image cropped as a base64 string. I decoded it and write it to a new image file so that it could be then saved in the database.

When it it gets to upload.save() I am getting the error.

`AttributeError: '_io.BufferedWriter' object has no attribute '_committed'`

I'm not sure what the problem is. This is my first time working with base64 images and im not sure if im missing something when i'm converting back to a file or what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a solution by using `ContentFile`

```
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

def upload_image(request):
        if request.is_ajax and request.POST:
        image = request.POST.get('image')

        image_name = request.POST.get('image_name')

        extension = image_name.split('.')[1].lower()

        image_name = '{}_{}_profile_image.{}'.format(request.user.first_name, request.user.last_name, extension)

        imgStr = image.split(';base64')

        data = ContentFile(base64.b64decode(imgStr[1]), name=image_name)

        upload = Upload(
            file=data,
            user = request.user.username
            )
        # Saves upload to S3 bucket
        upload.save()
    data = {

    }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

It converts the base64 string to a file that is readable by django.